# How do I setup this association between 3 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models: `User`, `UserType`, and `UserStatus`.

Examples of the data I am recording for Type & Status are:

**Type**

- Buyer
- Seller

**Status**

- Buyer-Willing
- Buyer-Hesitant
- Seller-Willing
- Seller-Hesitant

`UserType has_and_belongs_to_many :user_statuses` and the vice versa applies.

But, when someone creates a `User` record, they should only be able to assign `Buyer-Willing` if the `user.user_type = 'buyer'` and the same applies to the rest of the options.

So basically, they chose Type = `Buyer`, then they see 2 options.

How do I setup this association between `User` and `Status`?

I have a feeling it has some `:through` association, but I tried `has_one :user_status, :through => :user_type` on my `User` model, and I got a weird error.

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

Also, how do I get it so that to find the type of the `user`, I can do `user.type` instead of `user.user_type` without changing the model name? It's easier for me to quickly understand, when I am in the code that this model belongs to the `user`. So I don't want to rename it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using active record models for the UserType and UserStatus as both seem like they would be better defined inside your User model as fields because they seem like they may not change over time? Also i think type may be a protected word.

Comment: They will change over time. That's why I made them models. Different users should be able to add different user types and user statuses. The examples I have given are just examples. But, there can be many, many types & statuses.

Comment: Can a status belong to multiple types? So might you have a status for example that belongs to both Buyer and Seller?

Comment: Adding on to @ADAM's comment, you may be over-optimizing your DB layout here.  Unless UserType & UserStatus were going to have multiple columns, I'd just make them attributes on the model and handle the rest via validations between the type & status.  Then in your view, you could put the logic to show the right combinations.

Comment: Validations where? On the model? Can you give me an example of what you mean when you say `handle the rest via validations...`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want something like this:

User

```
belongs_to :type, class_name: "UserType"
belongs_to :status, class_name: "UserStatus", before_add: :validate_status

def validate_status
  return false unless type
  return false unless status.types.include?(type)
  true
end
```

UserType

```
has_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :user_statuses
```

UserStatus

```
has_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :user_types
```

I think the `validate_status` function can return `false` if you want to cancel the transaction, but the documentation only seems to mention throwing an exception.

Speaking of documentation, I think everything I suggested is covered here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: Not quite. A `User` can only have 1 Status & 1 Type at any one time. It can have a `type` without a status...but not vice versa (i.e. in order to have a status, it has to have a `type`).

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread. Editing...

Comment: By the way about your :through error, has_one :through something which has_many won't work. How would it know which one you meant?

Comment: That's exactly what the error was coming up with - it was some nil error that I have never seen before. So I assume it was related to that.